# Combining pagination and refinement in webmatrix/razor

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, razor, paging, webmatrix

I am trying to combine two of the tutorials provide by Mike Brind. Seperately they work, but combined they don't, and I'm sure it's just a simple change I need to make.

I want to display a query over several pages, but if I change a search parameter, I want it to update. Here is my code (using Mike's books example):

```
@{
    Page.Title = "Paging Books";
    Page.Header = "View Books";

    var pageSize = 3; 
    var totalPages = 0; 
    var count = 0;
    var page = UrlData[0].IsInt() ? UrlData[0].AsInt() : 1;
    var offset = (page -1) * pageSize;

    var db = Database.Open("Books");
    var sql = "Select Count(*) From Books " + 
           "Inner Join Authors on Books.AuthorId = Authors.AuthorId " + 
           "Inner Join Categories on Books.CategoryId = Categories.CategoryId";
    count = (int)db.QueryValue(sql);
    totalPages = count/pageSize;        
    if(count % pageSize > 0){
        totalPages += 1;
    }
    sql = "Select Title, ISBN, Description, FirstName, LastName, Category From Books " + 
           "Inner Join Authors on Books.AuthorId = Authors.AuthorId " + 
           "Inner Join Categories on Books.CategoryId = Categories.CategoryId " +
           "Order By BookId OFFSET @0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @1 ROWS  ONLY;";

    var result = db.Query(sql, offset, pageSize);

    var categories = db.Query("Select CategoryID, Category FROM Categories");
}

<form method="post" action="">
    Select Category:
    <select name="CategoryID">
        <option value="">-- View All Books --</option>
        @foreach(var c in categories){
            <option value="@c.CategoryId">@c.Category</option>
        }
    </select> <br />
    <input type="submit" name="Action" value="Select" />
</form>           

<p>Page @page of @totalPages</p>
@if(IsPost){
    foreach(var row in db.Query(sql, offset, pageSize, Request["CategoryID"])){
        <h2>@row.Title</h2>
        <p><strong>Author:</strong> @row.FirstName @row.LastName<br />
            <strong>ISBN:</strong> @row.ISBN <br/>
            <strong>Description:</strong> @row.Description <br />
            <strong>Category: </strong> @row.Category</p>
    }
}


@{
    for (var i = 1; i < totalPages + 1; i++){
        <a href="/Paging/@i">@i</a>
    }
}
```

This code currently shows all info in the correct pages, but when I change the `Category`, it doesn't just show results that match, it still shows all categories.

Comment: If you're not getting responses, it's an indication that you've probably *not* put enough information into your question. The right thing to do is to re-read your question, try to work out more useful information to add, and to continue to investigate it yourself and add info from that. The **wrong** thing to do is to mark your question as answered and then repost it with *no changes* from before.

Comment: I did re-read it, and make edits, and still got no response, so this was the only option, sorry.

Comment: No, this wasn't the only option. [Setting a Bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties): "In order to get good answers, you have to put effort into the question. Edit the question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer the question. This will naturally bump the question and get more people interested in it.

However, if after doing this, you feel a particular question still isn't getting enough attention, adding a bounty may help."

Comment: Thanks, you've been extremely helpful :s Can you offer any useful advice on my question, or are you just bored?

Comment: Gavin: Damien *did* offer useful advice.

Comment: @Gavin5511 because I don't have access to Mike Brind's tutorials (or I just don't know where to get them), can you provide a [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) of the data? This will allow users to *possibly* reproduce your error using the code above.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "it doesn't just show results that match". Do you mean no books are listed or all books are listed without the filter of category?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your asp code is incomplete. You only have SQL code to return the full list of books. Nowhere does it include a statement to filter according to the category selected by the user.

Before you do:

```
var sql = "Select Count(*) From Books " + 
       "Inner Join Authors on Books.AuthorId = Authors.AuthorId " + 
       "Inner Join Categories on Books.CategoryId = Categories.CategoryId";
```

you need to test if the request contains the attribute CategoryID with a non-empty value. If not empty define a different sql to filter on the category. Like so:

```
if(!Request.QueryString["CategoryID"].IsEmpty() ) {
    var sql = "Select Count(*) From Books " + 
           "Inner Join Authors on Books.AuthorId = Authors.AuthorId " + 
           "Where Books.CategoryID=@0";
    count = (int)db.QueryValue(sql, Request.QueryString["CategoryID"])
}
else {
    var sql = "Select Count(*) From Books " + 
           "Inner Join Authors on Books.AuthorId = Authors.AuthorId "; // no need for 2nd inner join
    count = (int)db.QueryValue(sql);
}
```

The same issue arises in the second sql statement. Do similar to above adjusting for offset.